# Package android application for release

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have never released an Android app before in the wild ( Android market places ).  I'm wondering what are you supposed to include in the manifest to identify your application.  Application name, copyright, company, home page ... etc.  Are there any given guidelines or expectations from the different stores that people should adhere to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I published my first app last week.

And there are quite a few things I didn't think about beforehand.

Particularly;

- creating icons for each resolution (and a high res one for the website)
- creating a key to sign the finished apk
- enabling proguard to obfuscate the generated apk
- writing decent copy to go on the market
- creating screenshots of the app in action
- considering what version number to give the first release

I followed the guidelines from the excellent "Programming Android" book
(its not your typical "heres an example" book... more of a "lets consider the whole android architecture")

But Google has documentation on its site
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html

This is a screenshot of part of the form you have to fill in.

[image: screenshot of the publish page]

Comment: oh, yea I forgot about this one, good point.  -> creating a key to sign the finished apk